# LoL Live API Usage

Tags: c#, api, http, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to figure out how to use the League of Legends live API. I've had success using the endpoints like this: /lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/{summonerName}

but when it comes to using endpoints like this (for live game data): GET https://127.0.0.1:2999/liveclientdata/allgamedata

I get the error
**"Cannot connect to destination host"**

Here is sample code I've been trying:

```
private IEnumerator Test()
    {
        string url = "https://127.0.0.1:2999/liveclientdata/activeplayername";

        using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
        {
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

            string error = webRequest.error;

            if (error != null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("[LoLAPI] - " + error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
            }
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: the url seems fine 
are you behind a proxy or something just wondering ?

Comment: Nope, just a regular Internet connection

Comment: Well it’s connecting to your machine so you need to check it’s running and listening on thar port

Comment: How do I check that port is running? Shouldn't it always be using that port given that's the port that LOL is using?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of UnityWebRequest will not accept self-signed SSL certificates by default. Try adding this:

```
public class UncheckedCertificateHandler: CertificateHandler
{
    protected override bool ValidateCertificate(byte[] certData)
    {
        // certificate validation always returns true
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then when you create the web request:

```
using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
{
    www.certificateHandler = new UncheckedCertificateHandler();
    yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
```

Or alternatively, just use `http://` if it is available.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried that also and no new information to share. The same error unfortunately.